# "Hast du auch alles?"—Do you have everything?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

What role "auch" plays in the sentence here?

Comment: Hi Abstract. Good questions in this forum demonstrate some initial efforts of the person asking to solve the problem. You should include your own thoughts, or what you found in books or whereever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It acts as an intensifier in this case, the same as `really` can in english. A better translation of `Hast Du auch alles?` would be `Do you really have everything?`